# jQuery, PHP, MySQL newly inserted data is only shown on page reload

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

With the code below I retrieve the content that is connected to a marker on a google map and display it in a container. Now the problem is that it works fine for content that was inserted into the database before the page is newly loaded. When new content is inserted into the database no content is shown until the page is reloaded. Anybody an idea how to solve this?

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {

var poslat = marker.getPosition().lat();
var poslng = marker.getPosition().lng();

var posData = {poslat : poslat, poslng: poslng};

      $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "getcontent.php",
          data: posData,
          success: function(data){ 

              $('.contentslide').slideDown('slow');

              $('.contentslide .container').html(data);

        });
});


<?php
$db_username = 'x';
$db_password = 'x';
$db_name = 'x';
$db_host = 'x';

$mysqli = new mysqli($db_host, $db_username, $db_password, $db_name);

$rs = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM locations WHERE lat=$_POST[poslat]");

$row = $rs->fetch_array();

echo $row['type'];
echo "<h1>" . $row['name'] . "</h1>" . "<br>";
echo "<p>" . $row['description'] . "</p>";

$mysqli->close();

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

What your saying kinda make sence. The page is loaded with what ever is in the database. If you add an entry in the database and do not reaload the page you will not see it.  Now if you are using a form to add a entry you might what to set your form action page to that same page. In that way when you post the new value to place in your database it will reload that page with that new entry as long as you place your new entry in the databse before you load the page. that would be a quick fix but you will still relaod the page. Only diffrence is that you wont need to press reload becuse its being done as you submit new entry.

The other option would be to use AJAX to reload only what you want to be reload in the page and it could also be done on an interval.

Basicaly if your looking at the page and another user add an entry you wont see it until you reload the page or unless you refresh a part of your page every 5 second using ajax.

It could also mean that you are loading the page before entering the values in the database

Make sure that all your html goes after your databse query.

Comment: how would you implement a partial reload in my example?

Answer (score 0):

you are sending json data, so try to use json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input") and data will be available through $_POST

Comment: where do I have to put json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input") ?

Comment: on the server side `$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"),true);
   $lat = $data['postlat'];`